# PostgreSQL regular expression capture group in select

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

How can the matched regular expression be returned from an SQL select? I tried using `REGEXP_EXTRACT` with no luck (function not available). What I've done *that does work* is this:

```
SELECT column ~ '^stuff.*$'
FROM table;
```

but this gives me a list of true / false. I want to know what is extracted in each case.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you're trying to capture the regex match that resulted from the expression, then `substring` would do the trick:

```
select substring ('I have a dog', 'd[aeiou]g')
```

Would return any match, in this case "dog."

I think the missing link of what you were trying above was that you need to put the expression you want to capture in parentheses.  `regexp_matches` would work in this case (had you included parentheses around the expression you wanted to capture), but would return an array of text with each match.  If it's one match, `substring` is sort of convenient.

So, circling back to your example, if you're trying to return `stuff` if and only if it's at the beginning of a column:

```
select substring (column, '^(stuff)')
```

or

```
select (regexp_matches (column, '^(stuff)'))[1]
```

Answer (score 10):

Use [`regexp_matches`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-matching.html).

```
SELECT regexp_matches(column,'^stuff.*$')
FROM table
```

> The regexp_matches function returns a text array of all of the captured substrings resulting from matching a POSIX regular expression pattern. It has the syntax regexp_matches(string, pattern [, flags ]). The function can return no rows, one row, or multiple rows (see the g flag below). If the pattern does not match, the function returns no rows. If the pattern contains no parenthesized subexpressions, then each row returned is a single-element text array containing the substring matching the whole pattern. If the pattern contains parenthesized subexpressions, the function returns a text array whose n'th element is the substring matching the n'th parenthesized subexpression of the pattern (not counting "non-capturing" parentheses; see below for details). The flags parameter is an optional text string containing zero or more single-letter flags that change the function's behavior. Flag g causes the function to find each match in the string, not only the first one, and return a row for each such match.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Amazon Redshift which uses PostgreSQL 8.0.2 (I should have mentioned this in the question). For me what worked was `REGEXP_SUBSTR`

e.g.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(column,'^stuff.*$')
FROM table
```